# Trying to scrape a link from webpage with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I do not understand why I can not retrieve the href link from this page with puppeteer:
[PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/#query=MES).

I have run Chrome and have the page inspected and found the desired `Headline`of the chemical and copied the `Selector` which looks like this:
`#featured-results > div:nth-child(2) > div.box-shadow > div > div.p-md-rectangle.flex-container.flex-nowrap.width-100 > div.flex-grow-1.p-md-left > div.f-medium.p-sm-top.p-sm-bottom.f-1125 > a`

and then I have run this JS code with nodejs.

```
     const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
     puppeteer.launch({ headless: true }).then(async browser => {
         const page = await browser.newPage()
         await page.goto('https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/#query=MES')
     //    const cookies = await page.cookies()
     //    console.log(cookies)
         const links = await page.evaluate(() => [document.querySelectorAll('#featured-results > div:nth-child(2) > div.box-shadow > div > div.p-md-rectangle.flex-container.flex-nowrap.width-100 > div.flex-grow-1.p-md-left > div.f-medium.p-sm-top.p-sm-bottom.f-1125 > a')].map(link => link.href))
         links.forEach(link => console.log(link))
        
         await browser.close()
     })
```

But my result is NULL.
Could anyone here open my eyes please?
Thanks.

Comment: Your css selector is way too specific. You cannot rely on the html tree to always be the exact same structure. Could you tell us which part of the page you're trying to extract exactly?

Comment: Have you tried `page.waitForSelector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to wait for the element to appear.
2. You need spread (`...`) to create an array from the `querySelectorAll()` result.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
puppeteer.launch({ headless: true }).then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/#query=MES')

    await page.waitForSelector('#featured-results > div:nth-child(2) > div.box-shadow > div > div.p-md-rectangle.flex-container.flex-nowrap.width-100 > div.flex-grow-1.p-md-left > div.f-medium.p-sm-top.p-sm-bottom.f-1125 > a')

    const links = await page.evaluate(
        () => [...document.querySelectorAll('#featured-results > div:nth-child(2) > div.box-shadow > div > div.p-md-rectangle.flex-container.flex-nowrap.width-100 > div.flex-grow-1.p-md-left > div.f-medium.p-sm-top.p-sm-bottom.f-1125 > a')]
                .map(link => link.href)
    )
    links.forEach(link => console.log(link))

    await browser.close()
})
```